# Symmetries of Rotation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, rotations, symmetric-groups

Consider the discrete symmetry $C_3$ (rotations by $120^\circ$ leave system invariant). 
I believe then the matrix describing this action is simply the rotation matrix (in 3d) (clockwise rotation): $$R(120^\circ)=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(120^\circ) & -\sin(120^\circ) & 0\\
\sin(120^\circ) & \cos(120^\circ) & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Consider also the following Permutation matrix, which maps basis vectors $e_1\rightarrow e_2$, $e_2\rightarrow e_3$, $e_3\rightarrow e_1$: 
$$P=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}.$$

I am confused about the following:

Don't these matrices fundamentally describe the same symmetry? Shouldn't they share the same  eigenvectors?

Thank you!

Comment: The rotation matrix you proposed is for a rotation around the $z$ axis, but the permutation is equivalent to a rotation around ${[1,1,1] \over {\sqrt 3}}$

Comment: Do you mean a rotation about $\frac{(1,1,1)}{\sqrt{3}}$ by $120^\circ$? Thanks

Comment: $120^\circ$ as you said

Comment: You can make $P$ the matrix for your first rotation (about the $z$-axis) through a suitable choice of basis. These rotations have the same _eigenvalues_, but nothing says that they have to have the same eigenvectors.